# Failed to load ApplicationContext. Testing

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockmvc

I want to learn how to test, but I get an error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration. If I remove `@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")`, then the tests pass without problems. But as soon as I add back `@TestPropertySource` and `@Sql(value = {"/create-user-before.sql"}, execution Phase = Sql.Execution Phase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)`. Returns an error

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1368e2f7 testClass = com.example.Sweater.LoginTest, locations = [], classes = [com.example.Sweater.SweaterApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = ["classpath:/application-test.properties"], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@4d84688f key = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebTestClientAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5d0bf09b, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@54422e18, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@7bba5817, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@4b3fa0b3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@1a75e76a, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@c77810aa], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [message]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
```

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
public class LoginTest {
    @Autowired
    private MessageController controller;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc; // MockMvc создает копию mvc для тестов

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")) // делаем запрос на главную страницу проекта
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk()) // ожидается что статус будет 200
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello, guest")))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Please, login")));
    }

    @Test// данный метод проверяет авторизацию пользователя
    public void accessDeniedTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/main"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("http://localhost/login"));
    }

    @Test
//   @Sql(value = {"/create-user-before.sql"}, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
    public void correctLoginTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(formLogin().user("admin2").password("1")) // смотрим совпадение логина и пароля
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/"));
    }

    @Test // метод на проверку неправильных данных пользователя
    public void badCredentials() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/login").param("username", "Alfred"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isForbidden()); // тут мы ожидаем 403 статус
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdNP2.jpg)

Comment: Your property file `application-test.property` seems not to contain all needed information about the data source. DB can not be found and tables not created.

Comment: Keep in mind the lifecycle. Your app starts, reads properties, creates persistence context and scanns for entities to create tables and if everything is up your test sources, DB script,.. will be executed but thats to late so persistence layer complains

Comment: @LenglBoy
This is what I assumed, but I do not understand how to solve the problem, I have already added new annotations

Comment: More annotations cant solve this since the context might still start before the properties and data source is configured. So the app complains on starting even before a test gets triggered. You need to extend the `application-test.property` file to that the datasource is fine.

Comment: You can also exchange `@SpringBootTest` by `@WebMvcTest`. The datayource (and services) will not ramp up. Just the http-layer. YOu need to mock service/repo and you can verify rest endpoints, exception handler and security anyway using less resources. Thats calles test-slicing.